# Python - matplotlib - setting margins

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to set margins of output figure please?

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [9, 4]
plt.savefig('figure.pdf')
```

I would like to have minimal white place to top and bottom margins. In the scrip, I remove axes, can it be the problem?

```
plt.xticks([]) 
plt.yticks([])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none') 
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot([1, 5, 3])
ax = plt.gca()

plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [9, 4]
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.savefig('figure.pdf')
```

[image: example of tight_layout()]